How to connect my esp32cam connected to Rpi hotspot, to my Mainsail setup on the same Rpi that is connected to my box
I have a bit of a problem, I'm a newbie in networking.
My setup :

Raspberry Pi 4 in my garage connected to Ethernet to my box with a long cable. This Pi is hosting Mainsail, with klipper for my 3d Print.
ip looks like 192.168.xxx.xxx
Esp32 Cam connected to a hotspot created on the Pi, because my garage is too far from my box.
ip looks like 10.10.xxx.xxx

My question : how can i setup my esp32 cam live stream on my Mainsail setting ?
I appreciate the help. Thx in advance.
